# How to make an intersection between two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an intersection between two arrays of objects.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bohr-v73ob?fbclid=IwAR3yQDnftREENi8lF6wCKYE_F09pimlLgfYca0B_oIPqYYHvbAf4cvnG-n4

```
const list1 = [
  {
    name: "skinType",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      },
      {
        id: "dry",
        label: "Dry"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "finish",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      },
      {
        id: "dry",
        label: "Dry"
      },
      {
        id: "matte",
        label: "Matte"
      },
      {
        id: "natural",
        label: "Natural"
      },
      {
        id: "radiant",
        label: "Radiant / Glow"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "texture",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "matte",
        labal: "Matte"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const list2 = [
  {
    name: "skinType",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      },
      {
        id: "dry",
        label: "Dry"
      },
      {
        id: "gandac",
        label: "mazga"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "finish",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I came up with a solution but it only can do the intersection based on the name key from the object. Now I need now to do the intersection based on the id from the keys array.

```
const intersection = (list1, list2) => {
  return list2.filter(drp => list1.some(rect => rect.name === drp.name));
};

const result = intersection(react, drupal);
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    name: "skinType",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      },
      {
        id: "dry",
        label: "Dry"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "finish",
    keys: [
      {
        id: "oily",
        label: "Oily"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code and other information directly in your question.  External links can (and often do) break over time.

Comment: Can you add the new expected result ? will it contain an object with name :texture too? if yes please add coz the current expected result doesn't contain it.  Seems like the given expected output is based on name instead of ids from the keys array

Comment: The expected result shouldn't contain the texture object because it is not present in both lists.

Comment: if its a union @aircraft721 then it must as its a union of two lists

Comment: this is not Union, @aircraft721 i think you meant intersection of two list

Comment: Yes, my bad. I edited the question. Thanks @ReeteshKumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const react = [
  { name: "skinType", 
    keys: [
      { id: "oily", label: "Oily" },
      { id: "dry",  label: "Dry" }
    ]
  },
  { name: "finish", 
    keys: [
      { id: "oily", label: "Oily" },
      { id: "dry",  label: "Dry" },
      { id: "matte", label: "Matte" },
      { id: "natural", label: "Natural" },
      { id: "radiant", label: "Radiant / Glow" }
    ]
  },
  { name: "texture", 
    keys: [
      { id: "matte", labal: "Matte" }
    ]
  }
];

const drupal = [
  { name: "skinType", 
    keys: [
      { id: "oily", label: "Oily" },
      { id: "dry",  label: "Dry" },
      { id: "gandac", label: "mazga" }
    ]
  },
  { name: "finish", 
    keys: [
      { id: "oily", label: "Oily" }
    ]
  }
];

var result = [];
for(var item1 of react)
  for(var item2 of drupal)
    if(item1.name == item2.name){
      var keys = item2.keys.filter(x => item1.keys.some(y => y.id === x.id));
      result.push({name: item1.name, keys})      
      break;
    }  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this works with a small change
var keys = item2.keys.filter(x => item1.keys.filter(y => y.id == x.id)[0]);

to be replaced with 

var keys = item2.keys.filter(x => item1.keys.some(y => y.id === x.id))

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about repeats?

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4];
const array2 = [5,6,7,8];

const union = (a1, a2) => [...a1, ...a2];

console.log(union(array1, array2));
```

If you don't want repeats

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const array2 = [4,5,6,7,8];


const distinct = (array) =>
  array
    ? array.reduce((results, item) => {
        if (!results.some((i) => i === item)) {
          results.push(item);
        }
        return results;
      }, [])
    : array;
    
const union = (a1, a2) => distinct([...a1, ...a2]);

console.log(union(array1, array2));
```

Comment: OP have added the `input` and `expected output`

Comment: As a sidenote (because the question is not about *union*  but *intersection*): For removing dupes, `[...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])]` is alot shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to avoid repeated values in the union result by first reducing the arrays to a mapping (via the `key.id` criteria), and then extracting the values of the mapping via `Object.values()` to obtain the union as an array of values.

The idea behind the intermediary mapping stage is to ensure that values in the resulting union are unique by the `key.id`.

In solution in code can look like this:

```js
const react=[{name:"skinType",keys:[{id:"oily",label:"Oily"},{id:"dry",label:"Dry"}]},{name:"finish",keys:[{id:"oily",label:"Oily"},{id:"dry",label:"Dry"},{id:"matte",label:"Matte"},{id:"natural",label:"Natural"},{id:"radiant",label:"Radiant / Glow"}]},{name:"texture",keys:[{id:"matte",labal:"Matte"}]}];const drupal=[{name:"skinType",keys:[{id:"oily",label:"Oily"},{id:"dry",label:"Dry"},{id:"gandac",label:"mazga"}]},{name:"finish",keys:[{id:"oily",label:"Oily"}]}];

/* Gather both arrays into a combined array via concat() and reduce() the result 
to obtain the union. The reduce() produces a mapping, and we obtain the union array
via Object.values() to extract the map's values as an array */
const union = Object.values([].concat(drupal, react).reduce((map, item) => {

  /* For each item of the keys sub-array, update the map with value "key" at key 
  "key.id" given that key.id is the union criteria */
  item.keys.forEach(key => {
    map[key.id] = key;
  })

  return map;
}, {}))


console.log(union);
```